# C# equivalent for these JAVA Collections methods

Tags: java, c#

hi I'm rewriting a java code in C# and I'm stuck here:

```
public void printSolveInstructions() {
    System.out.print(getSolveInstructionsString());
}

public String getSolveInstructionsString() {
    if (isSolved()) {
        return historyToString(solveInstructions);
    } else {
        return "No solve instructions - Puzzle is not possible to solve.";
    }
}

public List<LogItem> getSolveInstructions() {
    if (isSolved()) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(solveInstructions);
    } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

I know how to rewrite the first two methods (it's for referencing the last one) but I don't know the equivalent for `Collections.unmodifiableList()` and `Collections.emptyList()`
`solveInstructions` is of type `List` here's the declaration in java and C#:

```
private ArrayList<LogItem> solveInstructions = new ArrayList<LogItem>() // java
private List<LogItem> solveInstructions = new List<LogItem>() // c#
```

*update*
I rewrote the `getSolveInstructions()` method in this way:

```
public List<LogItem> getSolveInstructions()
    {
        if (isSolved())
        {
            return solveInstructions.AsReadOnly();
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<LogItem>();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is ide gives me an error when I use `.AsReadOnly()`

Comment: An empty list would just be `new List<LogItem>()`.  And you can get a read only collection by calling `List<T>.AsReadOnly()`.

Comment: Change return type to `IList<LogItem>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns either a `List<LogItem>`, or an `IReadOnlyCollection<LogItem>` (produced by call to `List<T>.AsReadOnly()` method; however, your return type is `List<LogItem>`, which is incompatible with the `IReadOnlyCollection<LogItem>`. Change your method return type to `IList<LogItem>`, which works for both types.

Note, since this method can return either a read-only or a read-write list, calling code should check the returned collection's `IsReadOnly` property, before attempting to modify it.